# Prove $\sum\limits^m_{k=0} \frac{2n-k\choose k}{2n-k\choose n}\frac{2n-4k+1}{2n-2k+1}2^{n-2k}=\frac{n\choose m}{2n-2m\choose n-m}2^{n-2m}$ for-

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, induction, binomial-coefficients

Let $n$ be a positve integer. Prove that$$\sum\limits^m_{k=0} \frac{2n-k\choose k}{2n-k\choose n}\frac{2n-4k+1}{2n-2k+1}2^{n-2k}=\frac{n\choose m}{2n-2m\choose n-m}2^{n-2m}$$ for each non-negative integers $m\leq n$. 
I know this is to be done by induction. Base case is easy. But I can't simplify expression for $(m+1)$. Please guide. 
 
**Edit:** $\large P(m+1)=P(m)+\frac{2n-(m+1)\choose m+1}{2n-(m+1)\choose n}\cdot\frac{2n-4(m+1)+1}{2n-2(m+1)+1}\cdot2^{n-2(m+1)}$ 

$\Large=\frac{n\choose m}{2n-2m \choose n-m}.2^{n-2m}+\frac{2n-m-1\choose m+1}{2n-m-1\choose n}\cdot\frac{2n-4m-3}{2n-2m-1}.2^{n-2m-2}$ 

 It must be equal to $\Large\frac{n\choose m+1}{2n-2m-2\choose n-m-1}.2^{n-2m-2}$ 
So lets try to simplify it- 
 
$\Large=\frac{n!(n-m)!}{m!(2n-2m)!}.2^{n-2m}+\frac{n!(n-m-1)!}{(m+1)!(2n-2m-2)!}\cdot\frac{2n-4m-3}{2n-2m-1}\cdot2^{n-2m-2}$ 

 $\Large=\frac{2^{n-2m-2}\cdot n!(n-m-1)!}{m!(2n-2m-2)!(2n-2m-1)}[\frac{2}{1}+\frac{1}{(m+1)}\cdot\frac{2n-4m-3}1]$ 

 $\Large=\frac{2^{n-2m-2}\cdot n!(n-m-1)!}{m!(2n-2m-2)!(2n-2m-1)}[\frac{2n-2m-1}{m+1}]$ 

 $\Large=\frac{2^{n-2m-2}\cdot n!(n-m-1)!}{(m+1)!(2n-2m-2)!}$ 

$\Large=\frac{\frac{n!}{(m+1)!(n-m-1)!}}{\frac{(2n-2m-2)!}{(n-m-1)!(n-m-1)!}}\cdot2^{n-2m-2}$ 
$\Large=\Large\frac{n\choose m+1}{2n-2m-2\choose n-m-1}.2^{n-2m-2}$ 
 
I think it is right. But is there any shorter way also?

Comment: Looks good to me (+1). Good job on the strategic manipulations. My only recommendation would be to write your proof more clearly, but even that is not that bad. Nice.

Comment: Yeah, can you help, I am a newbie at Latex. :(

Comment: Explain the downvote, downvoter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This reduces to a telescoping sum
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{\binom{2n-k}{k}}{\binom{2n-k}{n}}\frac{2n-4k+1}{2n-2k+1}2^{n-2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{(2n-k)!}{k!\,(2n-2k)!}\frac{n!\,(n-k)!}{(2n-k)!}\left(1-\frac{2k}{2n-2k+1}\right)2^{n-2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\left[\frac{n!\,(n-k)!}{k!\,(2n-2k)!}2^{n-2k}
-\frac{n!\,(n-k)!}{(k-1)!\,(2n-2k+1)!}2^{n-2k+1}\right]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\left[\frac{n!\,(n-k)!}{k!\,(2n-2k)!}2^{n-2k}
-\frac{n!\,(n-k+1)!}{(k-1)!\,(2n-2k+2)!}2^{n-2k+2}\right]\\
&=\frac{n!\,(n-m)!}{m!\,(2n-2m)!}2^{n-2m}\\
&=\frac{\binom{n}{m}}{\binom{2n-2m}{n-m}}2^{n-2m}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Nice manipulation. However, OP wrote "I know this is to be done by induction.", so I will deduct .01 point.

Comment: To me, that doesn't mean that induction is required; it sounds as if the OP is *assuming* it is to be done by induction.

Comment: It's always nice when there are multiple different proofs of a result.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion, its good. (y) @robjohn